# Getting Unexpected CallbackManager, in facebook integration android

Tags: android, facebook

please help me i am getting Unexpected CallbackManager, please use the provided Factory. in facebook Android

Logcat:

```
Process: com.thepetmet, PID: 27675
Unexpected CallbackManager, please use the provided Factory.
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.registerCallback(LoginManager.java:128)
        at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.registerCallback(LoginButton.java:445)
        at com.thepetmet.Login.LoginActivity.FacebookLogin(LoginActivity.java:244)
        at com.thepetmet.Login.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:236)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Well what does your code look like?

Comment: i am using  _callbackManager_  as static which is not initialized so it's got null value and simply crash so i always prefer individually each screen having it's own **CallbackManager**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You must call this: 
`CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();`
And only afterwards you can use the callbackManager

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue and realised my callbackManager was `null`...